# Can some part of my app have their own tabbar in a iOS app?

Tags: navigation, ios, tab-bar

I trying to design my iOS app, and I’m going to 2 bottom tab bar on different page. I would like if it’s good and a another better way exists.

Here is why:

When I log in my app, I would like user to be in the main page « Projects ». 
It’s like a dashboard. Here I have a list of projects and tabbar with Projects, Search, Settings as tab.

When user clicks on one of the projects, I’m going to the Home of the project, with a new tabbar with « Home, Documents, Add, Memories ».

Tabs of this tabbar is only available for « Project » not « ProjectS »

Tabs of Projects « Could be » on Project but I think should be a mess.

**So question is, can I continue on this way? Or Is there a better way to handle that (only 1 tabbar or something...)?**

*Edit : Or is it okay if the first main screen "Projects" doesn't have a tabbar to avoid user to be confuse?*

Answer (score 1):

If the home is a list of projects, then you can have a nav bar at the top with search and settings (icons) on the right. When the user selects a project and moves to the next page with details of the project, have a tool bar at the bottom with the rest of the options. Neither tab bar nor toolbar can have a multitude of options, so the number of items will have to be limited and the rest managed in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the tab bar at the bottom unexpectedly, and it should be available on all pages (don't show it conditionally based on context). If you haven't done so, I suggest you read Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines on navigation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/navigation/) and on the [different types of bars](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/).

Consider:

- How often do you expect users to switch between projects? How many projects do you think they will hold, a handful or several hundreds? If it's few, consider an interface similar to the Twitter app, where you switch navigation using the tab bar, but on the top-left side you can open a side panel to switch between account [projects] and settings.
- When listing projects, you may not need different tabs for search and settings. You could make the settings an icon in the toolbar, and the search field always visible at the top (like in Mail, Settings, Contacts). This works better for a table list with only the same type of items.
  Some apps have their own tab for searching (App Store, Music) but consider that they bring in a wider variety of search results. If you'd like to offer a feature to search within projects and not just by name in the list of projects, consider whether having it alongside projects would have been logical anyway.
- Avoid having **actions** like “Add” in a tab bar; these should go in the toolbar at the top, matching the type of element you are adding.

This was a bit too long for a comment, but without further context it's difficult to map out what you're trying to do. Perhaps draw a hierarchy of the information in your app and share that with us (using Balsamiq Mockups or draw.io, for example) and we could provide more actionable answers!